# Override ShopifyApp Module Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to override [ShopifyApp's new method](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/lib/shopify_app/sessions_concern.rb) but not sure where to start. Basically I need to add another field to get a `params`:

**/lib/shopify_app/sessions_concern/new.rb:**

```
module ShopifyApp
  module SessionsConcern
    module New
      def new
        if params[:field] == "abc"
         authenticate if params[:shop].present?
        end # or else ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To use that module, I would do something like this in a controller:

```
ShopifyApp::SessionsConcern.prepend ShopifyApp::SessionsConcern::New
```

But there's no where to use that. How to go about this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding is overriding. The following would do it for you without any `prepend`ing (having that you are loading the code from `lib` directory):

```
# lib/shopify_monkeypatching.rb
module ShopifyApp
  module SessionsConcern
    def new
      if params[:field] == "abc"
       authenticate if params[:shop].present?
      end # or else ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Ive dont that. In my `new` method, Ive put a `puts` but nothing is printing in the console when I go to the `/login` page.

Comment: @Sylar are you sure that you are loading lib files? just out of curiosity put the whole code into, say, `application_controller.rb` (after last `end`) and see if your `raise` or whatever appears

Comment: Yes. It prints when in `application_controller.rb` But not when in `/lib/new.rb`

Comment: @Sylar now we know it works properly. Your job now is to force Rails to load this file. Alternatively you can create a directory `app/monkey_patches/` and put this file there `app/monkey_patches/shopify_session.rb`. All files from `app` directory are autoloaded

Comment: In `application.rb` I have: `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"` Shouldnt that do?

Comment: @Sylar, try with `Rails.root.join('lib')`, because `"#{Rails.root}/lib"` is a string, not a `Pathname` object. P.S. It is sometimes a recommended practice to put `lib` folder under `app` directory because of reasons I named above. You can also consider this as a resolution to an issue.

Comment: My `lib/` works ok with other modules so not sure I need to change anything. Other methods may fail.

Comment: @Sylar I showed you how to override the method, we checked whether it works - it does. I explained how to overcome issue you have faced by providing few ways. Let me know if there's anything else I can help you with. P.P.S. did you restart the server?

Comment: Restarted, nothing. Added `app/lib/new.rb`, with entire code, nothing. Add: `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`, restarted, nothing.

Comment: @Sylar may be try to eager_load lib dir: `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

Comment: I was reading few post and you are correct: keep `lib` under `app` but what worked is, in `application_controller.rb` I have at the top: `require './lib/shopify_app/sessions_concern'` Not sure that's correct. Remember Im using Rails 5.

Comment: @Sylar I'm currently upgrading to Rails5, so unfortunately not yet familiar with all changes. But glad you have it working

Comment: Question, using `require` in `application_controller` is ok?

Comment: @Sylar It sounds a bit off conventions truly to say.. But it is strange that putting the code into `app` directory did not work.

Comment: @Sylar hey, here is an article about Rails5 loading, http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/07/22/solutions-to-potential-upgrade-problems-in-rails-5/, as I said before: did you try `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`? (and of course, restarting)

Comment: @Sylar you've read the corresponding part in the article, right?

Comment: Going to now.  Thanks for the help. One way or another I'll accept or upvote. I'll reply later.

Comment: Hola. Just to update, Rails 5 had `config.eager_load = false`. Set to `true` with `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` works. Thanks!

Comment: @Sylar great you've figured it out!